# Error when using direct comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was given the following exercise:

Determine whether the following series converges or not. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$$

I had assumed that this series diverges, so I used the direct comparison test, and it confirmed my assumption. Upon looking at the solutions, I realized it actually converges. After reviewing my attempt again, however, I can't seem to find my mistake. Can someone see what I did wrong?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n}-1 \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}-1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

As this is a Riemann $\zeta$-Function with $s=\frac{1}{2}$, this series diverges; hence, the original series must also diverge.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}-1 \right) \ne \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Limit comparison is probably a bit more natural here - besides, it suffices to show that $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$ diverges (which it does by the p-test).

Comment: also, the original sum involves positive  quantities. As soon as you compared it to a sum of negative quantities, you had an empty conclusion. More common is to multiply numerator and denominator (in the original sum) by the conjugate of the numerator

Comment: @Mimir2902 Btw do you study at ETH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** First of all your last equality

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}-1 "=" \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
is not true as $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}-1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-1$.

**2.** You already ran into a dead end with the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}-1$$
as it tends to $-\infty$ (using the [$n$-th term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth-term_test)) and doesn't tell you anything about convergence or divergence of the original series.

**3.**

To easily prove that the original seris converges:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ n^{1.5}}.
$$
The convergence of the last series can easily be proven with the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). If you want to be explicit and it is equal to $\zeta(1.5)≈2.61238$.

**4.** I wouldn't call the last series *"this is a Riemann $ζ$
-Function with $s=1/2$"* as this is not the case. The value $\zeta(1/2)$ is in fact a real number but isn't defined through the original series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$.

Answer (score -1):

You should note that
$$
\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}= \dfrac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\leq \frac{1}{2 n^{3/2}}
$$

So, you see that the series is actually convergent.